# Linking HTML pages to Android App without copying HTML files to app

Tags: android, html, hyperlink

I wish to create a notifications tab in my app but how am I supposed to keep updating it without having to provide updates in my app through the store?

I am planning to provide live html pages to provide the link but I wish to show that html page in a specific layout on the app.

If you have any other ideas, please comment below.

Comment: you can use webview for that

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `WebView`. `WebView` is a view that displays web pages.

Answer (score 0):

check a little bit Google Cloud Messages ( GCM ) it can give you an idea , by the way is strongly recomended to use Firebase Clud Messging ( FCM )

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/